# HTML/CSS Image Appearing in the wrong area?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a users image on my `nav-bar`, but the image is not appearing where it should be, It should apear to the right of the header although it isn't. It is appearing after a `<ul>`. I'm not sure why.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/HXnNu/

Im not sure if I need to try something along the lines of

```
fixed: right;
```

or what. What do you think?

Also how would I go upon vertically centering that image?

Thanks!

Comment: It is advisable to include the code (css and html) here in the question as well.

Comment: Try adding a float:right to the style on the img tag.  The image won't just go right because you want it to - you have to send it to the right.

Comment: @SurrealDreams I dont want to float it to the of the whole side bar, I want to have it to the left of the header, which is "Chatterr"

Comment: Not clear with your needs. Can you please post an image which describe your needs clearly?

Comment: @Mr_Green http://pbrd.co/ZtlDEN

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing currently to send it to the right of the page. `float:right` can accomplish this for you.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7NCw/)

```
.navbar img {
    float:right;
}
```

Ideally the `<img>` would have some class and you would target it using the class just so future issues don't occur if you include more `<img>` tags in `.navbar` in the future.

### Edit

If you want the `<img>` to the left of the header you can organise your tags like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- ... -->
    <img src="http://harrisonbh.com/chatterr/user_files/profile_img/2dff134978.jpg" alt="Profile Image" style="height: 35px; display: inline;float: left;">
    <a class="brand" href="index.php">Chatterr</a>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

And then put `float:left` on the `<img>`:

```
.navbar img {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to float it to the of the whole side bar, I want to have it to the left of the header, which is "Chatterr"

Answer (score 0):

width  is the  main issue

take one div   and cover your ul and image text box in that

and give the  width according to total width available  on the  main div

ie

```
<div width="900px; float:left;">   <ul width="600px">  </ul style="width:300px;float:left;"> <img> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could not use `fixed: right;` but `position: fixed;` `right: 0;` or `float: right;`. For your question may be `right: 0;` okay!